# Maximum Likelihood Estimator of Uniform($-2 \theta, 5 \theta$)

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood

> Let $X = (X_1, \dots, X_n)$ be a random sample from the Uniform($-2 \theta, 5 \theta$) distribution with $\theta > 0$ unknown. Find the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) for $\theta.$ Furthermore, determine whether the MLE $\hat{\theta}$ is a function of a one-dimensional sufficient statistic for $\theta.$

Let $M = \max{ \{X_1, \dots, X_n \}}$ and $L = \min{ \{X_1, \dots, X_n \}}.$ Consider the likelihood function of $\theta$ $$L(\theta; x) = \prod_{k=1}^{n} f(x_k ; \theta) = \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{7 \theta} \cdot \mathbf{1}_{(-2 \theta, 5 \theta)}(x_k) = \frac{1}{(7 \theta)^n} \cdot \mathbf{1}_{(-2 \theta, 5 \theta)}(m) \cdot \mathbf{1}_{(-2 \theta, 5 \theta)}(\ell) \cdot \prod_{k=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{\mathbf{R}}(x_k).$$ By the Factorization Theorem, it follows that $(M, L)$ is sufficient for $\theta,$ and in fact, it is easy to show that $(M, L)$ is minimal sufficient for $\theta.$ Our candidates for the MLE include $M,$ $L,$ and functions of $M$ and $L,$ e.g., the midrange $\frac{M-L}{2};$ however, I am running into difficulty finding the MLE and establishing that it gives a maximum.

On first glance, it appeared that $\hat{\theta} = L$ because $m \geq \ell$ implies that $\frac{1}{(7m)^n} \leq \frac{1}{(7 \ell)^n};$ however, this is only true if $m \geq \ell > 0.$

Reading a few other posts on here, I considered the possibility that the midrange $\frac{M-L}{2}$ is the MLE for $\theta.$ Of course, the difficulty arises out of the fact that there are many possibilities for $L$ and $M$: $m \geq \ell > 0,$ $m \geq 0 > \ell,$ and $0 \geq m > \ell,$ to name a few.

Can anyone offer any helpful insight or tips?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The likelihood function is $(7\theta)^{-n}$ for $-2\theta <L$ and $5\theta>M,$ otherwise zero. So the maximum likelihood value of theta is the smallest value of $\theta$ satisfying $-\theta <L/2$ and $\theta>M/5.$ Thus it is  $\max\{M/5,-L/2\}.$

Comment: I agree that the maximum likelihood estimate -- and therefore, the maximum likelihood estimator -- is the smallest value of $\theta$ such that $\theta > M/5$ and $\theta > -L/2;$ however, I do not understand why this gives that the maximum of $M/5$ and $-L/2$ is the MLE. By our initial argument, should it not be the minimum? Moreover, what can be said about the question of whether the MLE is a function of a one-dimensional sufficient statistic? It does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Well if $\theta < M/5$ or $\theta < -L/2$ then the likelihood is zero (since we are outside the support of the PDF) so it must be the smallest thing not less than either of them, i.e. the max. The MLE is certainly a function of a one-dimensional statistic, since $\max\{M/5,-L/2\}$ is a one dimensional statistic. (It's a somewhat ugly function of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ but it's still just one number computed from them, not unlike, say, the sample mean). And it is a sufficient statistic since the likelihood can be written $L(\theta) = (7\theta)^{-n}I(\theta \ge \max\{M/5,-L/2\})$.

Comment: Can it not be shown that $(M,L)$ is minimal sufficient? Furthermore, does it not make sense that $\max{ \{M/5, -L/2 \}}$ is a function of $(M,L)?$

Comment: What do you means, does it not make sense? Not sure if you're asserting it does or doesn't make sense and what is the significance? It obviously is a function of $(M,L)$ so I'd say it makes sense but again I'm not sure what you're trying to say. As for your first question I've already said that I think $\max\{M/5,-L/2\}$ is sufficient.

Comment: I apologize if I am being unclear. Certainly, $g(M,L) = \max{ \{M/5, -L/2 \}}$ is sufficient: it is a function of the minimal sufficient statistic $(M,L);$ however, to me, that implies that $g(M,L)$ is NOT a function of one-dimensional sufficient statistic. Furthermore, it is my understanding that there are no one-dimensional sufficient statistics, as $(M,L)$ is minimal sufficient.

Comment: Why do you think $(M,L)$ is minimal sufficient? I agree sufficient, but why minimal?

Comment: Let $X = x$ and $Y = y$ be two observations. Check that the ratio of likelihoods $L(\theta ; x)/L(\theta ; y)$ is independent of $\theta$ if and only if $m(x) = m(y)$ and $\ell(x) = \ell(y).$

Comment: Not quite sure I follow but I think you might have things backwards. For instance a function of a sufficient statistic is not necessarily sufficient (functions can easily lose information). My argument for $g(M,L)$ being sufficient was based on factorization. If it is sufficient I believe that it is minimal sufficient, not $(M,L)$ since it is a function of $(M,L)$ but not vice versa. So if you are positive $(M,L)$ is minimal sufficient, there must be a problem with my factorization argument and $g(M,L)$ must not be suffficient.

Comment: I think I follow your previous comment now and yeah same deal, if $g(M,L)$ is sufficient that's an if but not an only if.

Comment: It is my understanding that any one-to-one function of a sufficient statistic is once again a sufficient statistic. Furthermore, a sufficient statistic is minimal if it possesses the most data reduction of any sufficient statistic, i.e., if it is a function of all other sufficient statistics. By our factorization, it is clear to see that $(M,L)$ is sufficient for $\theta.$ Furthermore, by my above comment, the ratio of likelihoods $L(\theta ; x) / L(\theta ; y)$ is independent of $\theta$ if and only if $m(x) = m(y)$ and $\ell(x) = \ell(y),$ hence $(M,L)$ is minimal sufficient for $\theta.$

Comment: I do see your point that $g(M,L)$ is a function of $(M,L),$ the obvious sufficient statistic, hence it seems to be the case that $g(M,L)$ is minimal sufficient. Can we check the ratio of likelihoods?

Comment: Clearly, $g(M,L)$ achieves the most data reduction, as well, since it reports one number as opposed to $(M, L),$ which reports two numbers. I believe that you are correct. Thanks for sticking with me.

Comment: Sounds like your intuition's on track now, but just to clarify: I think the key is that $L(\theta) = (7\theta)^{-n}1(\theta > M/5)1(\theta>-L/2) = (7\theta)^{-n}1(\theta > g(M,L)).$ (Or in your notation $1_{(-2\theta,5\theta)}(m)1_{(-2\theta,5\theta)}(l) = 1_{(0,\theta)}(g(m,l))$.) So it is sufficient but not necessary that $m(x)=m(y)$ and $l(x) =l(y).$ We only need $g(m(x),l(x)) = g(m(y),l(y))$. Regarding your first remark, one-to-one is a strong assumption.,$g$ is not one-to-one. The fact that it remains sufficient despite this means we have dimensionality reduction.

Answer (score 2):

The support of $L(\theta; x)$ is given by $L\ge -2 \theta$ , $M\le 5\theta$; or, equivalently $\theta \ge M/5$ and $\theta \ge -L/2$. Or $$\theta \ge T \triangleq 
 \max(M/5,-L/2)$$

Because over its support $L(\theta; x)$ (for $n>1$) is decreasing, then $  \theta_{ML}=T$

---

Regarding $(M,L)$ being or not minimal sufficient:

You say " it is easy to show that $(M,L)$ is minimal sufficient for $\theta$" but I don't think that's true.

$$L(\theta; x)=\frac{1}{(7\theta)^n}\mathbf{1}_{[M \le 5 \theta]} \mathbf{1}_{[L \ge -2 \theta]}=\frac{1}{(7\theta)^n} \mathbf{1}_{[T\le\theta]} $$
tells us that both $(M,L)$ and $T$ are sufficient. $T$ is clearly minimal. Because $T=f(M,L)$ (but not the reverse) then $(M,L)$ cannot be minimal.

Put in other way, consider some $x_1$ with $(M_1,L_1)=(100,-2)$ and some $x_2$ with $(M_2,L_2)=(100,-4)$, so that $T_1=T_2=20$

Then $\frac{L(\theta; x_1)}{L(\theta; x_2)}=1$ (doesn't depend on $\theta$), but $(M_1,L_1)\ne (M_2,L_2)$, hence $(M,L)$ is [not minimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Minimal_sufficiency).

Comment: Can you justify your claim that $L(\theta ; x)$ is decreasing over its support? I do not see why this is true. Furthermore, can you confirm my claim that $(M,L)$ is minimal sufficient for $\theta?$ What can be said about the question of whether $\theta_{ML}$ is a function of a one-dimensional sufficient statistic? It does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Over its support, we have the function $(7\theta)^{-n}$ which is decreasing for $n\ge 1$